# checking type of range in python's typing module

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

It's about missing `typing.Range`.

There is no type for `range` in the `typing` package, but at the same time we see `typing.re.Match`, which is a package-oriented type.
The `typing.sequence` or `typing.Iterable` is too broad.

Is there a better way to check `range` type and only `range` type? Besides using:

```
range_instance.__class__ == range
```

*update*:

To be clear, I mean some of the types in typing are including all elements or aspects of something, like `typeing.Iterable` (generic type, that's fine)

On the other hand, there are also very **specific** types like

`typing.Generator`, `typing.Tuple`, `typing.Dict`, `typing.re.Match`
`typing.AsyncContextManager`, ...

but not

`typing.Range`

Fact 1: a `range` type is a different type in python
(for example, a range has extra optimization given for checking elements there, and sometimes it makes sense to know if you're dealing with list or range)

Fact 2: a `typing` module seems to covers all aspects of types.
(see imports and logic there if you doubt)

Knowing this, I think `typing.Range` is missing.

Otherwise, people are confused about which one to use:

`r: range` or `r: typing.Iterable` or creating a custom alias

The difference between type hints and type checking doesn't matter here.

Comment: Anything wrong with `isinstance(range_instance, range)`?

Comment: You are confusing two similar but different things: the typing module offered generic types for type annotation which serve the purpose of documentation and **hint**ing. A type check on the other hand is solid **check** that an object is derived from a defined class or parent class. It might be valid in some usecase but it generally opposes the duck-typing concept of Python.

Comment: @Klaus: no, I don't because `typing` serves not only generic types and since that module is based on the `types`, `collections`, `abc` and others, there is no problem to use that package not only for type hinting but also for type checking. Of course, we're not limited to that module for type checking. Maybe it shouldn't be the first try at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main idea of the `typing` package [interface segregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle). In most cases you *should not* care whether the argument passed is actually a `range` object, but about some aspect of its functionality. In most cases, that functionality is covered by the `typing.Iterable` (I don't understand what you mean by "too comprehensive").

On the other hand, if you want to explicitly check for the range type, just use `isinstance(x, range)`

Comment: I've updated question above, thank you for your link. I think the ISP is broken in typing module for range, due to not providing `typing.Range`.

Comment: @SławomirLenart Why would you expect `typing.Range` to exist? `range` is neither an interface (like `typing.Iterable`) nor a generic (like `typing.List`); there is absolutely no reason for `typing.Range` to be a thing. It would be literally the same thing as `range`.

Comment: @SławomirLenart: I think it's the exact opposite. `range` is just an iterable for most purposes. So, you should be covered by `iterable`. However, you're right, the `typing` module is a bit inconsistent regarding what it represents. Keep in mind though that it's an afterthought, and it's relatively new. On the other hand, the `abc.collections` follows interface segregation more clearly

Answer (score 5):

Instead of the (impossible because typing.Range doesn't exist):

```
from typing import Range
    
def foo(r: Range) -> None:
    ...
```

Just do:

```
def foo(r: range) -> None:
    ...
```

Since `range` is already a type as well as a factory function, you don't need a separate type for ranges.

Note that types like typing.Dict exist because, while `dict` is already a type, there wasn't previously support for using builtin types as generics, so you couldn't do dict[str, int] as a type annotation and had to do Dict[str, int]. But since `range` isn't logically a generic, there was no need for an a separate type in `typing` corresponding to `range` to support generics.

Comment: so which one to use? `r: range` or `r: typing.Iterable`?

Answer (score 2):

You asked:

> Is there a better way to check `range` type and only `range` type, besides:
>
> ```
> range_instance.__class__ == range
> ```

I think you can use [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) for this case (I tested it in `Python 3.x`):

```
>>> isinstance(range(10), range)
True
>>> isinstance(list(range(10)), range)               # this is a list
False
>>> isinstance([1, 2, 3, 4], range)                  # this is a list
False
>>> isinstance((e for e in range(10)), range)        # this is a generator
False
```

As you can see, it works correctly in recognizing range objects and it also does not get confused by lists or generators.